# Repeatability issue of uninitialized value error from valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am using valgrind to track memory errors. I've noticed that valgrind detects an uninitialized value error sometimes for the same code and test conditions. What could be the reason for the strange behavior?

```
Run1:
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./parcob cobalt_tet map_tet 
==14034== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14034==    at 0x36936D5B20: profil_counter (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==14034==    by 0x36936302CF: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==14034==    by 0x369AE7290C: std::istream::operator>>(int&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==14034==    by 0x414C68: mesh::__FVMESH<int, double>::ReadCobaltMesh(char const*, char const*) (unsmesh_io.h:975)
==14034==    by 0x419948: main (main.cpp:47)
==14034==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14034==    at 0x369AE4E3C0: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==14034== 
==14034== 
==14034== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14034==     in use at exit: 263,884 bytes in 1 blocks
==14034==   total heap usage: 8,923 allocs, 8,922 frees, 495,130 bytes allocated
==14034== 
==14034== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14034==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14034==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14034==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14034==    still reachable: 263,884 bytes in 1 blocks
==14034==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14034== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)

Run2
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./parcob cobalt_tet map_tet 
==14035== 
==14035== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14035==     in use at exit: 263,884 bytes in 1 blocks
==14035==   total heap usage: 8,923 allocs, 8,922 frees, 495,130 bytes allocated
==14035== 
==14035== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14035==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14035==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14035==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14035==    still reachable: 263,884 bytes in 1 blocks
==14035==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14035== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Sorry for posting a verbose output.

*NOTE*: Application was compiled using Intel compiler suite

Comment: The reason is probably because you forget to initialize something.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why doesn't this show up in case of run2?

Comment: Seems like there is a (sometimes?) uninitialized variable in libstdc++. But it could be a "false positive" in valgrind too.

Comment: Are you sure the two runs do the exact same thing? Have you tried e.g. stepping through the code on two consecutive runs in a debugger to see that they really do the same thing? Have you checked what you do around line 47 of the file main.cpp, or around line 975 of the file unmesh_io.h?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, the two runs do the exact same thing. line 975 is std::ifstream::operator>>